# How can I run a event handler before Page.IsPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to run code in a button event handler but the `if(Page.IsPostBack)` conditional is running first and contains a redirect so the event never runs.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        (do some stuff with save button pressed...)

        // then return the same page to prevent another post on refresh 
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

and on that page there is another button that calls a handler:

```
protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    (do other stuff..)
}
```

Is there a way to run the handler first or a way to check which button was clicked so I can add a conditional to the redirect?
Thanks.

Comment: “IsPostBack is running first” — show the *full* code. `Page.IsPostBack` is a *property* and it cannot “run first”.

Comment: Any server-side event is going to occur during a post-back. The `Page_Load` will run before your event handler does. Processing your save logic should occur in it's relevant event (Save_Click, maybe?) instead of relying on the `Page_Load` during postback.

Comment: @chaggy No, you cannot trigger `button click event`, before `page load event`. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Jonathon Chase, Adding a `Save_Click` handler instead of running the code in `Page_Load` did it for me. If you feel like adding it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is actually by design in WebForms. To keep things stateless, a full postback occurs whenever you wish to fire off a server-side event.

So the short answer is no, you cannot force your event to occur before the `Page_Load` does.

However, you can restructure your design a bit to get the behavior you desire. At the moment, it looks as though you are depending on a PostBack having a occurred to execute your save logic. Instead of handling the logic in your `Page_Load` event, it could be handled in an event appropriate to how your user is expecting to save.

If saving is triggered through a button press, then moving logic for handling the save and redirect to a `Save_Click` event will allow other events related to PostBack to execute their own logic as well.